# Unrecognized Selector for SideBar Instance

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, menu, sidebar

I'm asking this question because the answer I received in this question: [How Do I Initialize Two Instances of NSObject in the same ViewController - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728420/how-do-i-initialize-two-instances-of-nsobject-in-the-same-viewcontroller-swift)

brought me in this direction. Whether I subclass as NSObject or UIViewController, I still receive the unrecognized selector when I change my code to what's below.

I'm still trying to be able to create a left and right SideBar. However, I cannot even get one SideBar to load now. I receive an error [UIViewController Center]: unrecognized selector sent to instance xxxxx.

This question is different from the other unrecognized selector instance questions I've seen because I'm not dealing with a button and have no outlets since everything is done programmatically. Hence, I can't specify a subclass that links to a `UIViewController` in the storyboard.

I feel like once I solve the selector issue the code will work. As the code is right now, the application compiles fine. The problem is the runtime error that I receive. I can provide information from the debugger if it's necessary.

Fwiw, it seems like the runtime is recognizing that I have a center, left, and right viewcontroller from the error message.

I haven't included the RightSideBar code because I think if the left SideBar runs the RightSideBar will run when I add the solution. I want to keep the code you have to read through as brief as possible.

Last thing to note, I'm reaching all of my print statements. I actually print through to the point where it says "I should be showing the sideBar".

Here is the code for the SideBar:

```
//optional delegate methods that select when the sidebar opens and closes.
@objc protocol SideBarDelegate : class {

func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex (itemIndex: Int)
optional func sideBarWillClose()
optional func sideBarWillOpen()

}

//this class sets up the actual sidebar.
class SideBar: UIViewController, SidebarTableViewControllerDelegate {


//width of the bar, tableview setup, and views for the sidebar
let barWidth:CGFloat = 175.0
let sideBarTableViewTopInset:CGFloat = 25.0
let sideBarContainerView:UIViewController = UIViewController()
let sideBarTableViewController:SidebarTableViewController = SidebarTableViewController()
var originView:UIViewController?

//var for dynamic effect and controlling the sidebar
var animator:UIDynamicAnimator!
weak var delegate:SideBarDelegate?
var isSideBarOpen:Bool = false

//initializer for the "SideBar" class.
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(nibName NibNameOrNil:String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil:NSBundle!) {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

}

convenience init(){
    self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

//initializer for the tableView of menu items.
init(sourceView: UIViewController, menuItems: Array<String>, menuImages: [UIImage]){

    self.originView = sourceView
    self.sideBarTableViewController.tableData = menuItems
    self.sideBarTableViewController.imageData = menuImages

    println("set initialization values")
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

    //initializing the views and animation for the menu.
    setupSideBar()
    animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: originView!.view)

    println("finished initialization")

    //swipe gesture recognition for opening the menu.
    let showGestureRecognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipe:")
    showGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    originView!.view.addGestureRecognizer(showGestureRecognizer)

    let hideGestureRecognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipe:")
    hideGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    originView!.view.addGestureRecognizer(hideGestureRecognizer)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    println("view loaded")


}

//this function handles the direction of swipes
func handleSwipe(recognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    if recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left {
        showSideBar(false)
        delegate?.sideBarWillClose?()
        println("closed the sideBar")
    } else {
        println("opened the sideBar")
        showSideBar(true)
        delegate?.sideBarWillOpen?()
    }
}

//function for setting up the sidebar.
func setupSideBar () {

    println("setup sideBar")

    //setting up the frame/outline of the side bar.

    sideBarContainerView.view.frame = CGRectMake(-barWidth - 1, originView!.view.frame.origin.y, barWidth, originView!.view.frame.size.height)

    //setting up the color of the sidebar.
    sideBarContainerView.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    //disables subviews from being confined to the sidebar.
    sideBarContainerView.view.clipsToBounds = false

    //placing the sidebar in the UIView
    originView!.view.addSubview(sideBarContainerView.view)

    //adding blur to the menu.
    let blurView:UIVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light))
    blurView.frame = sideBarContainerView.view.bounds
    sideBarContainerView.view.addSubview(blurView)


    //setting up controls for the sidebar
    sideBarTableViewController.delegate = self
    sideBarTableViewController.tableView.frame = sideBarContainerView.view.bounds
    sideBarTableViewController.tableView.clipsToBounds = false

    //disabling the scroll feature. Delete to keep the scroll feature.
    sideBarTableViewController.tableView.scrollsToTop = false

    //This will remove separators in the UITableCell. Delete to keep separators.
    sideBarTableViewController.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None

    //This sets the background color of the sidebar and creates the inset.
    sideBarTableViewController.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    sideBarTableViewController.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: sideBarTableViewTopInset, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

    //reloads the sidebar and adds the container view to the sideBarTableViewController.
    sideBarTableViewController.tableView.reloadData()
    sideBarContainerView.view.addSubview(sideBarTableViewController.tableView)
    originView?.addChildViewController(sideBarContainerView)
    sideBarContainerView.didMoveToParentViewController(originView)

}


func showSideBar(shouldOpen: Bool){
    animator.removeAllBehaviors()
    isSideBarOpen = shouldOpen

    println("I should be showing the sideBar")

    //simple if and else statements to define the direction of animation and intensity of animation
    let gravityX:CGFloat = (shouldOpen) ? 0.5 : -0.5
    let magnitude:CGFloat = (shouldOpen) ? 20 : -20
    let boundaryX:CGFloat = (shouldOpen) ? barWidth : -barWidth - 1

    //controls the behavior of the animation.
    let gravityBehavior: UIGravityBehavior = UIGravityBehavior(items: [sideBarContainerView])
    gravityBehavior.gravityDirection = CGVectorMake(gravityX, 0)
    animator.addBehavior(gravityBehavior)

    let collisionBehavior: UICollisionBehavior = UICollisionBehavior(items: [sideBarContainerView])
    collisionBehavior.addBoundaryWithIdentifier("sideBarBoundary", fromPoint: CGPointMake(boundaryX, 20), toPoint: CGPointMake(boundaryX, originView!.view.frame.size.height))
    animator.addBehavior(collisionBehavior)

    let pushBehavior:UIPushBehavior = UIPushBehavior(items: [sideBarContainerView], mode: UIPushBehaviorMode.Instantaneous)
    pushBehavior.magnitude = magnitude
    animator.addBehavior(pushBehavior)

    let sideBarBehavior:UIDynamicItemBehavior = UIDynamicItemBehavior(items: [sideBarContainerView])
    sideBarBehavior.elasticity = 0.3
    animator.addBehavior(sideBarBehavior)


}

func sidebarControlDidSelectRow(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    delegate?.sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(indexPath.row)
}

}
```

Here is the Home ViewController:

```
class Home: UIViewController, SideBarDelegate {

//*** Must put logout code into the logout button it should log the user out if they press it ***

var sideBar:SideBar = SideBar()

var homeImage = UIImage(named: "Shine Home")
var profileImage = UIImage(named: "Shine Profile")
var shareImage = UIImage(named: "Shine Share")
var aboutImage = UIImage(named: "Shine About")
var helpImage = UIImage(named: "Shine Help")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //setting up the menu items for the sidebar.
    sideBar = SideBar(sourceView: self, menuItems: ["Home", "Profile", "Share", "About", "Help"], menuImages: [homeImage!, profileImage!, shareImage!, aboutImage!, helpImage!])

    sideBar.delegate = self


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(itemIndex: Int) {

    switch itemIndex {

    case 0:
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") as! Home
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    case 1:
        performSegueWithIdentifier("profile", sender: self)
    case 2:
        performSegueWithIdentifier("share", sender: self)
    case 3:
        performSegueWithIdentifier("about", sender: self)
    case 4:
        performSegueWithIdentifier("help", sender: self)

    default:
        break
    }
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

Comment: attempting `let sideBarContainerView:UIViewController = UIViewController() as! SideBar` produces a runtime error: could not cast value of type UIViewController to SideBar. This is only way I could think of to add some sort of signal to the code that the SideBar is unique.

Answer (score 0):

This situation of unrecognized selector stems from the runtime not knowing what specific object you want to activate.

The runtime sees `sideBarContainerView` object, which is acceptable for the compiler.

The problem is that your animation behavior is for views. Your UIViewController Object has not descended into UIViews. You need to add `.view` to all `sideBarContainerView` in your `showSideBar` function.

If you breakdown your function and just use `isSideBarOpen` as the bool for your if statements in the constants and place it in the initialization of your menu then you'll get the Selector error immediately.

That's just a second way to point to fact that the error is past your last print statement `"I should be showing SideBar`.

If you do that then your menu will load. So far, I have no solution for getting both menus to initialize as a left and right menu.